# Variable doesn't change even though I can return the updated value

Tags: javascript

I have this code:

```
var playySlideNumber = "1";
var run = function playSlides (playySlideNumber){
    $(".slider.secondLayer").css("opacity", "0");
    $(".slider.secondLayer.n"+playySlideNumber).css("opacity", "1");
    if  (playySlideNumber < 5) {
        playySlideNumber = parseInt(playySlideNumber) + 1;
    } else {playySlideNumber = "1"}
    return playySlideNumber
}
setInterval(function(){run(playySlideNumber)}, 3000);
```

I need that function `playySlides()` returns `playySlideNumber` so that every time the `setInterval` runs it has the correct `playySlideNumber`.
The problem is that `playySlideNumber` keeps constant `= "1"`.

Also, would it be easier to use a `setTimeout` that recursively calls `playySlides()`?

Comment: You're missing quite a few (at least two) semicolons.

Comment: Make a fiddle please

Comment: Nowhere do you update the global `playySlideNumber` variable, which is why it stays at 1.

Comment: @RaymondChen - it does: `playySlideNumber = parseInt(playySlideNumber) + 1;`

Comment: @JamesHyde Nope, that's the parameter `playySlideNumber`. This code is confusing because it has a global variable with the same name as a parameter.

Comment: @RaymondChen Ok, so how to do it?

Comment: Change the name of the argument inside of the function so that it doesn't match the global variable. Then you can change the global from within.

Comment: Or get rid of the parameter entirely and just operate on the global directly.

Comment: …or better use `playySlideNumber = run(playySlideNumber)`

Comment: @Bergi no that would only update it once

Comment: You can also use `window.playySlideNumber` to reference the global without changing the parameter name.

Comment: I don't care with down votes but if someone reads the comments will see that this is not as immediate/easy as some might think. Down voting makes this appear a stupid question when it's not.

Comment: @JonathanGray: Not when it runs repeatedly in the `setInterval` callback?

Comment: @Bergi actually you're right I wasn't looking at the code when I replied and the way it's coded... Yeah you're right that would work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove the argument because it's overshadow the the global variable and don't need to return value from run function because it's not used anywhere:

```
var playySlideNumber = "1";
var run = function playSlides(){
    $(".slider.secondLayer").css("opacity", "0");
    $(".slider.secondLayer.n"+playySlideNumber).css("opacity", "1");
    if  (playySlideNumber < 5) {
        playySlideNumber = parseInt(playySlideNumber) + 1;
    } else {playySlideNumber = "1"}
}
setInterval(run, 3000);
```

Comment: Why the downvote? This is a correct answer. +1 from me

Answer (score -2):

The problem is that the first time this code runs, playSlideNumber is a string, then you try to evaluate if it is less than 5 but it will never be so, so it goes in the else branch which puts "1" (a string) back into your variable.

Comment: This is wrong. I did downvote this one. Strings can be compared like numbers. That's not what the issue is.